# Uncommon Time Signatures

Tags: time-signatures

I'm trying to learn about time signatures.

I'm pretty sure I've correctly identified the "colored" ones in the attached image,
but cannot find any info on the web on the non-colored ones.

Could someone help with these please?

[image: time signature diagram]

Comment: There aren't any colours here. Do you mean the time signatures you've put names to? In that case - what does 'Odd' mean?

Comment: That is correct (the colored image would not attach) so the ones with names 'were' colored. Odd same as Irregular I believe.

Comment: If you’re trying to learn time signatures from the beginning, I would ignore /16 time signatures for now. They are so rare and when you understand the others you’ll understand the /16 also. Normally time signature learning focuses on 2/4, 3/4, 4/4, 6/8, 9/8, and 12/8 only, because once you know those you can combine and compare to understand any time signature, even ones you haven’t listed.

Comment: I think 'odd' and 'irregular' were invented by people who had difficulty counting in anything but 2s and 3s.

Comment: Apart from names (some will be antiquated), how will the chart help you learn about time signatures?

Comment: It's not so much the names, but how they will be beamed. For example would 16 eighth  notes (in 8/4 time) be beamed as 4 groups of 4 notes, or 2 groups of 8 notes?

Comment: The 11s can also be divided into [2+2+2+2+3] or [4+4+3].  15/8 is compound quintuple FWIW.

Comment: "15/8 is compound quintuple" - thanks - that is what I was looking for - that tells me it would be grouped [3+3+3+3+3]

Comment: Be aware that some of the less common time signatures *don't* necessarily *have* to be 'regular', even if the top number can be divided equally. 15/8 may well be 5x3, but some composer may decide it was to be divided, for example, into 3+3+3+2+2+2, to fit with the emphases within the bars.

Comment: 8/8 is an odd time signature usually [3+3+2]

Comment: Thanks for all the additional info - it all helps

Comment: 8/8 can also be [3+2+3]. 9/8 can be [3+2+2+2] (permute as required). Modern rhythms don't fit into the neat little categories beloved of 19th century pedants.

Comment: How isn't 15/8 or 15/16 [5+5+5]? Also, the only piece I've ever heard in 11/8 time is [2+2+3+2+2] (the *Mario Kart 64* race results theme).

Comment: @Dekkadeci - not saying it isn't. It often is, but doesn't **have** to be.  Generally, sub-beats are divided in 2s and 3s, so actually 5 itself would often be 2+3 or 3+2. But the bigger the top number, the more chances are it will be sub-divided in lots of different ways. Not just the basic simple mathematical way. Obviously some things, like 11 and 13, will only divide 'oddly'. (As in unevenly!).

Comment: @Dekkadeci: 15/8 can be considered as 5/4 with a triplet beat, or 'compound triple'. 5 X 3 as opposed to 3 X 5.

Answer (score 0):

Some time signatures have been given names - you've identified them correctly so no problem. Others don't have specific names, but you can still use them when composing if the music goes that way. You haven't said why you need to know the names. Personally I've never bothered with the names since I stopped taking theory exams, and I thought them a waste of time even then.

The numerator defines the number of beats in the bar, the denominator defines the note-length used for each beat (you probably know all this). So 3/4 means 3 beats of quarter-notes (crotchets in English!) and is fairly common so was given a name. 13/8 means 13 notes of eighth-notes (quavers) but was rare so wasn't given a name.

Don't forget that the names are fairly old, and come from a time when even 5/4 was regarded as highly dangerous. Nowadays it's pretty normal.

Comment: It's not so much the names, but how they will be beamed. For example would 16 eighth notes (in 8/4 time) be beamed as 4 groups of 4 notes, or 2 groups of 8 notes?

Comment: The numerator doesn’t always tell you the number of beats in a bar. For example, 12/8 time has four beats per bar.

Comment: @ToddWilcox True - I was being too simplistic. I have to say that outside a classroom I've never heard any of the 'official' names used.